# How can i manage empty array having a different locale value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays

imagine this behavior , your Locale applications is english 'en'.

But in my code i have to show the correct values comparing with the locale application in this case is 'en', but some of this values doesn't have 'en' translation so, in this case i have to fill the app with the value that i have even if is not english. example:

```
const localeApp = en;
```

```
const arrayWithLocaleValues =[
    [
        [
            {
                "translation": 'Barley protein rate',
                "locale": {
                    "value": "en",
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                
                "translation": "Dominant barley variety",
                "locale": {
                    "value": "en",
                }
            },
            {
                
                "translation": "Variedad de cebada dominante",  
                "locale": {
                    "value": "es",
                }
            },
            {
             
               "translation": "Variété dominante d'orge",              
                "locale": {
                    "value": "fr",
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "translation": "Année de récolte",
                "locale": {
                    "value": "fr",
                }
            }
        ],
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                
                "translation": "Sample comment",
               
                "locale": {
                    "value": "en", 
                }
            },
            {
                
                "translation": "Comentario de muestra", 
                "locale": {
                    "value": "es",
                }
            },
            {
                "translation": "Commentaire échantillon",   
                "locale": {
                    "value": "fr",   
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

so having this array and mapping the same& comparing with the locale = 'en' like this:

```
 const newLocaleValues = arrayWithLocaleValues.map((newLocaleValues) =>
      newLocaleValues.map((values) =>
        values.map((newValues) => {
          if (locale === newValues.locale.value) {
            return newValues.translation;
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
```

I received this result:

```
[
    [
        [
            "Barley protein rate"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "Dominant barley variety",
            null,
            null
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            null
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "Sample comment",
            null,
            null
        ]
    ]
]
```

As you can see one of the array is completely empty, the third one, so my question is, what can i do to receive the result even if is not the correct locale? i have to fill the value is neccesary i can't have a empty object.

i wanna send a default value when i'm not getting any match

```
Expect result:


[
    [
        [
            "Barley protein rate"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "Dominant barley variety",
            null,
            null
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
          "Année de récolte"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "Sample comment",
            null,
            null
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i already achieve what i wanted, if someone find this helpfull will be great.

```
const mapped = arrayWithLocaleValues.map((a) =>
      a.map((b) => {
        let def = '';
        const arr = b
          .map((c) => {
            if (locale == c.locale.value) {
              return c.translation;
            }
            def = c.translation;
          })
          .filter((val) => null != val);
        if (!arr.length) {
          return [def];
        } else {
          return arr;
        }
      }),
    );
```

Result:

```
[
    [
        [
            "Barley protein rate"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "Dominant barley variety"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "Année de récolte"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "Sample comment"
        ]
    ]
]
```